# Using Init 0 to shutdown computer

Tags: 10.10, shutdown, restart

Okay so i have ubuntu 10.10 and for some reason if i shutdown with the shutdown button in the top corner under power or `shutdown -h now` or `shutdown now` these things end up restarting my computer.

Will it damage my computer like the hardware, operating system, etc if i use `sudo init 0` to shutdown all the time, because that shudown(restart) crap makes my windows to start acting strange after a few times and i think it could end up damaging my hardware so i have decided to use `init 0` instead.

Let me know thanks! I really don't like unity(11.04) or Gnome3(11.10) so id rather stay at 10.10 i am enjoying it!

Comment: Have you had any kernel updates recently? I'm guessing kernel bug as `shutdown -h now` also does not work, if you do can you try booting into an older kernel and seeing if the same behavior exists

Comment: Not sure exactly how to do that just recently got into linux it has been a great experience other than this issue.

Comment: when the pc is starting up hold in shift to access the grbu boot menu, older kernel versions should be listed there. Ignore recovery and memtest entries.

Answer (score 1):

Using `init 0` shouldn't harm the system itself, as it should run through all the necessary stuff. But you should make sure that you manually exit out of all your apps first. The safest thing would be to log out, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to log in on the console and shut down from there.

Comment: See when i log out and hit ctrl+alt+F1 i put in the command and it asks me to log in, is the password the same as my username? I tried putting it in and it told me login incorrect?

Comment: The password is your regular password that you use when you log in, change system settings, install software, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For a single user / desktop system you should not notice any differences.

From the shutdown man page: It prevents further logins and notifies currently logged in users before changing the runlevel.

See `man shutdown` for more details

Comment: Okay so i was looking under shutdown details and it let me use sudo shutdown -P now and it worked perfectly i guess the -h command is just having issues? Or maybe an update fixed the issue i am not sure but ill just use shutdown -P now to shutdown from now on. ill check if other shutdown methods are working properly.

Comment: I don't know what i did but it seems to be working fine now the shutdown under the power symbol even works now? I did a sfc/scannow on my windows the other day to fix issues with the system maybe that did something or because of an update I am not sure truthfully but its working so thats all that matters to me.